# NHibernate with LINQ, operator "==" generate OR with "is null"

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, orm

When I do this query:

```
var query = from entity in session.Query<Entity>()
            where entity.Status != 2
            select entity;
```

NHibernate generates this SQL:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE_NAME ALIAS
WHERE ALIAS.SITFIL <> 2 
       or ALIAS.SITFIL is null /*this 'or' is the problem*/
```

Why does NHibernate do this?

**Edit**: The 'or' causes a performance issue on my application

I want to generate just:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE_NAME ALIAS
WHERE ALIAS.SITFIL <> 2
```

Without 'Or field is null'

The mapping not is nullable:

```
[Property(Column = "SITFIL", NotNull = true)]
public virtual TypeEnumOfProperty Status { get; set; }
```

The enum:

```
public enum TypeEnumOfProperty
{
    [Display(Name = "Ativa", Description ="Ativo")]
    Ativa = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Inativa", Description = "Inativo")]
    Inativa = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Inativa e oculta", Description = "Inativo e oculto")]
    InativaOculta = 2,
}
```

**Edit:** If I change the TypeEnumOfProperty to int the SQL is generated like I want, if change to TypeEnumOfProperty or long then was generated with the 'or'.

If I use 'equals' on comparison, NHibernate generates the where clause without 'or'.

Does someone know why and how solve this?

Comment: is the status property on Entity nullable? If so, you can try entity.Status.Value != 2 or entity.Status != null && entity.Status != 2

Comment: The property not is nullable:
      [Property(Column = "SITFIL")]
      public virtual TypeEnumOfProperty Status { get; set; }

Comment: If the field is not nullable, then the 'or' statement will always return false (since it can never be null) so it really isn't an issue.

Comment: The problem is related with performance, I don´t want a 'or' on the 'where' clause.

Comment: Please, show your `TypeEnumOfProperty` type.

Comment: @AndrewPrigorshnev I added the enum on question...

Comment: what happens if you explicitly mark the column at not nullable instead of relying on the underlying type?

Comment: @Fran, the same behavior...

Comment: This behavior was changed in NHibernate 5.3.0 and now map column as not null should help. [link](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/1996)

Answer (score 1):

It is doing what you query is saying i.e.

```
var query = from entity in session.Query<Entity>()
        where entity.Status != 2
        select entity;
```

return everything but not equal to 2.
So, you if you don't need null, improve you query.

```
var query = from entity in session.Query<Entity>()
            where entity.Status != 2 && entity.Status != null
            select entity;
```

always go with safer side, who knows what will break your logic.

Comment: I wan't to generate the 'or is not null', this causes a performance problem. The selection of the 'where' works, but I want a 'where' without the 'or'.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior. It isn't a bug per se, but it could be improved.

You can work around the problem by doing this:

```
var query = from entity in session.Query<Entity>()
            where !(entity.Status == 2)
            select entity;
```

The execution plan will be identical to what you're aiming for. You could even insert a custom query provider which rewrites all this for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can :

1) see this [article](https://blog.devart.com/string-enum-representation-in-entity-developer.html) to set enum in hbm.xml mapping file

```
     <property name="Status"  type="YourNamespace.Enums.TypeEnumOfProperty, YourNamespace.Enums"/>
```

2) use equals in linq in better than ==

Comment: Can you demonstrate by example that using `equals` would remove the `null` check?